# localhost unable to connect after google oauth2 authorised

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-sa360-api

[image]I have tried the quickstart script and the search ads 360 script i initially had the issue with. Both versions give me an error when trying to get credentials from the google oauth flow.

The quickstart script I used is below

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the People API.
    Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Call the People API
        print('List 10 connection names')
        results = service.people().connections().list(
            resourceName='people/me',
            pageSize=10,
            personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
        connections = results.get('connections', [])

        for person in connections:
            names = person.get('names', [])
            if names:
                name = names[0].get('displayName')
                print(name)
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: looks like successful authentication initially]

following this I am able to continue through the authentication page and then land of the last error page attached. For context I have tried to use a google VM and a python script running in R studio to run but always get the same error.

Comment: which error page? like what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Tried using pycharm and the script finally worked